# Pandas apply function on dataframe over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the following code I get an KeyError: ('a', 'occurred at index a'). How can I apply this function, or something similar, over the Dataframe without encountering this issue?

Running python3.6, pandas v0.22.0

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), 
                  columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.apply(lambda x: add(x['a'], x['c']))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think need parameter `axis=1` for processes by rows in [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> **axis**: {0 or 'index', 1 or 'columns'}, default 0
>
> **0** or **index**: apply function to each column
> **1** or **columns**: apply function to each row

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: add(x['a'], x['c']), axis=1)
print (df)
0   -0.802652
1    0.145142
2   -1.160743
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The 1 in 'axis=1' signifies ‘columns' and conversely 'axis=0' means 'rows', So setting 'axis=1' in the apply function tells the function move *along* the column, or, in other words, iterate on rows. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need apply, you can directly add the columns. The output will be a series either way:

```
df = df['a'] + df['c']
```

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': [5, 6]})
df = df['a'] + df['c']
print(df)
#  0    6
#  1    8
#  dtype: int64
```

Comment: I had in mind a more complex function, not just adding, but something that can't be vectorised in this way.

Comment: @labjunky, care to share this complex function with us? It may be an interesting problem in itself..

Answer (score 0):

you can try  this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add(df):
   return df.a + df.b

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3), 
                      columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.apply(add, axis =1)
```

where of course you can substitute any function that takes as inputs the columns of df.